# Access Query Criteria To Be Left Blank Using a Form

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database filled with projects for my company and relevant information for those projects. One of which is the `"account manager"` for the project.

I've made a form with a combobox named cboAccountManager where the user can filter project information by choosing one of the account managers. I've linked this to a query (& from that a report) where the criteria under `"account manager"` is `[Forms].["Form Name"].[cboAccountManager]` and this works fine.

I'd like to set it up where if the combobox in the form is left blank all projects are shown for every `"account manager"`. Currently if it is left blank no projects are shown.

I tried using an IIF statement where if `[Forms].["Form Name"].[cboAccountManager] = ""`, statements such as: Like "`*", "*", ""` were used to force the query to show all the results but it always comes back with no results. Any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: I take it your query looks for a specific value in an account manager field if the combo box is not null.  If it is null you want the query to return all records where the account manager field is not null - try **NZ**  (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c).  I'm guessing it will be something like `NZ( [Forms].["Form Name"].[cboAccountManager],Not AccountManagerField Is Null)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes if nothing is entered into the combobox I'd like it to return all records. Unfortunately using the NZ command as suggested still comes up with 0 results if the combobox is null.

Comment: Thanks for your help Darren. Using correct Access terminology like yourself I found an answer on google. Instead of: IIF([combobox] Is Null,Like "*",[combobox]) this works: Like IIF([combobox] Is Null,"*",[combobox])

Comment: Could you post your SQL (edit your original post) - NZ or @LiamH response should work.

Comment: Just checked and NZ worked a treat by putting Like at the start of the statement similar to the IIF statement I stated then. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following:

`Like [forms]!["Form Name"]![CboAccountManager] & "*"`